# How to reload a child view without reloading whole state in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that has multiple views declared in it as follows:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home.details.item', {
        url: '^/details',
        views: {
          'chartsView': {
            templateUrl: 'charts.html',
            controller: 'chartsCtrl'
          },
          'gridView': {
            templateUrl: 'grid.html',
            controller: 'gridCtrl'
          },
          'detailsView': {
            templateUrl: 'details.html',
            controller: 'detailsCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
```

I need to reload one of the views without reloading the whole state, without using `$state.go($state.current,null , {reload: true})` , and if possible, from the `chartCtrl` reload `detailsCtrl`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, that the `UI-Router` solution should be built arround `*states*`, not views.
*(I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QLOBRuDp7fX9x5xXqYqL?p=preview))*. Other words, if there are

- some views which should **not** be reloaded and
- some other views, which **should be** reloaded

... it calls for state nesting. Let's move that view into child state:

```
  .state('home.details.item', {
    url: '^/details',
    views: {
      'chartsView': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.charts.html',
        controller: 'chartsCtrl'
      },
      'gridView': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.grid.html',
        controller: 'gridCtrl'
      },
      // 'detailsView': {
      //   templateUrl: 'details.html',
      //   controller: 'detailsCtrl'
      // }
    }
  })
  .state('home.details.item.more', {
    views: {
      'detailsView@home.details': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.details.html',
        controller: 'detailsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

We also need a state, which will do the **reload**. We could use other way, e.g. with some changing parameter in state `more`, but that would mean to change the param value on each call. With this specil state, we can easily reload our state `'more'`:

```
.state('reload', {
    parent: "home.details.item",
    views: {
      'detailsView@home.details': {
       // this controller will just redirect to 'more' and make it fresh...
       controller: ['$state', function($state) { $state.go('^.more')}],
      }
    }
 })
```

And with these simple controllers we can do all that required stuff:

```
.controller('chartsCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
   var childName = ".more";
   $state.go(childName); // default is a sub state 'more' 
})
.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.when = Date.now();
})
```

Having this: we can call this to reload just details:

```
<a ui-sref="reload">force reload detail view</a>
```

Now, when navigating to reload, we will be redirected to state "more" and our view will be rerendered.

SUMMARY:

In general, UI-Router represents state machine. I would strongly suggest:

> Do not worry to think in **`states`**. *`Views` are just their representation in the DOM.*

If there are some features related, they most likely represent state. If others do not relate (should be changed often or rarely) they belong to other state. It could be parent, child or sibling...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QLOBRuDp7fX9x5xXqYqL?p=preview)